# Mongo Date or Number (epoch) as index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query I run *often* where I use the Date to sort by. Basically I want to grab the next user due for some "processing" based on the last time they were processed, but I don't want to process users more often than every X minutes.

I have this query;

```
Users.findOne({'status':'active',  'lastCheck': {"$lt": sinceTime}).sort({"lastCheck": "ascending"}).exec(callback);
```

I know that for this to work I need to set `lastCheck` as an index, but this is a `Date`. Is it better to store that as a Number or Date?

Maybe there is a better way to do this altogether?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/): "BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).". So if you store it as millis you would not get any benefits really. I think it's better to store it as Date because you get all kinds of data integrity checks and conversions in your stack. Using `$lt` is absolutely appropriate with dates.

As for the index you'll have to pick carefully. MongoDB can use only one index in the query condition. Here you are querying by 2 fields, so maybe a compound index would be better - depends on your data. Perhaps I would even create only 1 index on `lastCheck`. You can use that same index in the `sort` since you are sorting by that field. Mongo is able to use another index for sorting purposes.